# QGIS 3 geometry/topology checking problem

Tags: qgis-3

I have a polygonal shapefile which has one overlap, where one polygon overlaps another polygon.

Vector -> GeometryChecker (Rule: must have no overlap) finds this error:
[image]

When I use the new QGIS 3.81 Vector -> Check geometries (with check for gap enabled) No error is shown:
[image]

Now I check with Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Check  Validity , also No error is shown:
[image]

Question: I am misusing Vector -> Check geometries and Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Check  Validity or is there a bug????

Test-data are here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yj981h8b948mz00/stuff.zip?dl=0

Comment: How exactly did you get to the 'check geometry' screen? I cannot find it under the vector menu. I did seem to find there the 'Check validity', but that is not the screen of your second picture.

Comment: @LMB - That is a core plugin which may need to be enabled from the menubar: `Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins`.

Comment: as @Joseph says its a core-plugin at least in qgis 3.81

Comment: the overlap is not invalid and is bigger than .1m^2 so doesn't show up in the 2nd and 3rd checks

Comment: I have been able to find the overlap with the check geometries plugin if the "Check for overlaps smaller than (map units sqr.)" variable is set to 0,0000000 instead of 0,1

Comment: Strange: Check for overlaps smaller than (map units sqr.)" variable is set to 0,0000000 seems to find ANY overlap while setting a value > 0 seems to find only overlaps SMALLER than this value? @Ian Turton